# Why is work done equal to force×displacement?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, definition, dimensional-analysis

I have understood that work done depends on force and displacement but I have not understood that why does the product of these two gives work done and not multiplied by some constants or raised to the power of something. It's very rare to find just the product of two quantities equals something. Is there any solid proof that when we should multiply the product or when to
raise to any power?

Comment: The constant in front of "work" in the SI system is "1" due to the way that SI units were defined.  The same cannot be said for other systems of units.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is behind the definitions of work and energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/277347/)